# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el valor del type en un input dinámico con Jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, entrada

Lo que estoy haciendo es tener dos inputs uno a lado del otro con un checkbox que lo que hace es convertir el tipo de `text` a `password` y un botón de agregar una nueva fila.

*Imagen De los inputs*
[image: Imagen De los inputs]

Y al darle click en add row se agrega en la parte de abajo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero el problema es que quiero que el segundo input pueda ser intercambiado entre texto y password y cuando se agregue abajo se quede con el tipo que le asigne.

¿Cómo puedo lograr esto con Jquery?

Parte de mi HTML es este:

```
<div class="span-23 margin_bot margin_top_b text_form_fieldname">
                <div class="margin_bot" id="itemRows2">
                    <input class="input_text input_size text_input span-6" type="text" name="add_qty" size="4" placeholder="Variables"/> 
                    <input id="password" class="input_text input_size text_input margin_bot span-11" type="text" name="add_name" placeholder="Valor" />
                    <span class="float_left margin_right">
                        <input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('password').type = this.checked ? 'password' : 'text'">
                    </span>
                    <input onclick="addRow2(this.form);"  class="button blue margin_bot" type="button" value="Add row" />
                </div>
            </div>
```

Y mis funciones de Jquery son estas:

```
var row2Num = 0;
function addRow2(frm) {
    row2Num ++;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+row2Num+'"><input class="input_text input_size text_input span-6" type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'" placeholder="Variable" disabled><input class="input_text input_size text_input span-11" type="text" name="'+frm.add_qty.value+'" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'" placeholder="Valor"><span class="float_left margin_right"><a class="link_pointer" onclick=""><img alt="Ocultar" src="/static/img/icon_locked.png" title="Ocultar"></a></span><input  class="delete-row button green" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+row2Num+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows2').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
    }

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
    }
```

Comment: esta parte `<input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('password').type = this.checked ? 'password' : 'text'">` realmente te funciona? <b/r> porque no lo cambian por `<input type="checkbox" onchange="this.checked ? 'password' : 'text' ">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo harias de la misma manera que hiciste con el checkbox.  Algo asi:

```js
var row2Num = 0;
function addRow2(frm) {
    row2Num ++;
    var type = document.getElementById('password').type;
    var row = '<p id="rowNum'+row2Num+'"><input class="input_text input_size text_input span-6" type="text" name="qty[]" size="4" value="'+frm.add_qty.value+'" placeholder="Variable" disabled><input class="input_text input_size text_input span-11" type="' + type + '" name="'+frm.add_qty.value+'" value="'+frm.add_name.value+'" placeholder="Valor"><span class="float_left margin_right"><a class="link_pointer" onclick=""><img alt="Ocultar" src="/static/img/icon_locked.png" title="Ocultar"></a></span><input  class="delete-row button green" type="button" value="Remove" onclick="removeRow('+row2Num+');"></p>';
    jQuery('#itemRows2').append(row);
    frm.add_qty.value = '';
    frm.add_name.value = '';
    }

function removeRow(rnum) {
    jQuery('#rowNum'+rnum).remove();
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<form>
<div class="span-23 margin_bot margin_top_b text_form_fieldname">
                <div class="margin_bot" id="itemRows2">
                    <input class="input_text input_size text_input span-6" type="text" name="add_qty" size="4" placeholder="Variables"/> 
                    <input id="password" class="input_text input_size text_input margin_bot span-11" type="text" name="add_name" placeholder="Valor" />
                    <span class="float_left margin_right">
                        <input type="checkbox" onchange="document.getElementById('password').type = this.checked ? 'password' : 'text'">
                    </span>
                    <input onclick="addRow2(this.form);"  class="button blue margin_bot" type="button" value="Add row" />
                </div>
            </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Esto es lo que queria! Funciona perfecto!

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con este:

```
<input type="checkbox" onchange="this.checked ? $('#password'').attr("type", 'password') : $('#password'').attr("type", 'text')">
```